# Difference between full Access Keys vs. Private Keys

Tags: nearprotocol

What is the difference between full Access Key and Private Keys?

The explanation here is quite limited. It would be great to know

- The Difference
- Examples when you would use which kind of key

Here is the link to the docs https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/integrator/integrating#access-keys

Answer (score 0):

Comparing private keys to full access keys is like comparing apple to oranges. When we talk about an access key, regardless of its permissions, we usually talk about a public-private key pair. The public key of the key pair is added to the account state that is stored on chain while the private key is stored on some local device that can be used to sign transactions through some client.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat of a misnomer situation.

There are 2 types of keys in Near:

- Full Access Key
- Limited Access Key or Function Call Access Key

Every key "pair" has a public and private part. These are often also called keys on their own i.e. my "public/private key." Keys are just data and usual looks like some random bytes. In near we use base58 encoding for string representations of these parts.

A private key is sometimes also called a secret key.